# Почему apache + nginx при обработке изображений отдает 500 ошибку?

Tags: php, apache, nginx

Есть php скрипт, который выполняет обработку большого количества изображений (ресайз, наложение вотермарков и тд.). Проблема в том, что скрипт по истечению 40 минут работы отдает 500 ошибку, а затем, с каждым последующим запуском отваливается еще раньше, хотя таймаут на выполнение запроса стоит около часа. В логи пишет **upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream**

**У Apache**

- max_execution_time 3600
- max_input_time 3600
- upload_max_filesize 512M
- post_max_size 512M
- memory_limit 512M

**У nginx**

- proxy_connect_timeout 3600s
- proxy_send_timeout 3600s
- proxy_read_timeout 3600s
- proxy_buffer_size          512k
- proxy_buffers              512   4096k
- proxy_busy_buffers_size 4096k
- proxy_temp_file_write_size 4096k
- client_max_body_size 30m
- client_body_buffer_size      4096k
- large_client_header_buffers 8 32k

В самом скрипте после обработки каждого каталога очищается дисковый кэш.
Как можно решить данную проблему, не прибегая к крону и/или запуску скрипта непосредственно на сервере?

Comment: Запускайте его из консоли. Представляете, что будет, если поисковый бот начнет его дергать каждые пятнадцать минут?

Comment: Вы привели логи nginx'а, а надо апача - он же ошибку отдает.

Comment: Apache ничего не записал в логи

Comment: Поисковый бот не получит доступ к этой странице, т.к. этот запрос будет вызываться из админки

Comment: ищите лучше, у вас может логи php отдельно настроены, а не в логи апача пишутся. Либо вы (или не вы) перехватываете ошибки и сами отдаете этот заголовок

Comment: если не знаете что делать - можете сами логи писать, чтобы знать где у вас скрипт падает. И попробуйте из консоли запустить - если нормально работать будет, значит в настройках что-то не то. И вы уверены, что именно эти конфиги использованы? Можно же запустить апач, потом поменять конфиг - а настройки-то старые будут.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оказалось что apache съедал всю оперативку, но в лог ничего не писал, а писал nginx. gc_collect_cycles() исправил ситуацию.

Comment: Скажите пожалуйста, а почему так мало хостингов предоставляющие услугу `nginx+apache`. Ведь если сайт с статикой и динамикой, то эта связка куда лучше чем просто `apache`.

Comment: Ну это уже от хостера зависит. Для простых проектов типа визиток, лендингов или корпоративных сайтов shared хостинг с apache вполне достаточно. А для остальных возможность заказать VPS/VDS и уже самостоятельно конфигурировать на свой вкус

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Смотрите логи выполнения `PHP`. Вы не те логи смотрите. У вас скорее всего скрипт спотыкается на обработке одного и того же изображения.

А вообще лучше используйте консольные скрипты и ставьте большие лимиты на все:

```
set_time_limit(0); // бесконечное выполнение скрипта, либо очень большой таймаут ставьте
ini_set('memory_limit', '1G') // укажите лимит на память побольше
ini_set('display_errors', E_ALL); // включайте вывод всех ошибок
```

При запуске в консоле переводите `STDOUT` и `STDERR` в файл для логирования:

```
$ php /var/www/myhost/my_script.php >> /var/log/my_script.log 2>&1
```

При необходимости запускайте через `CRON` и `flock` для проверки запуска только 1 скрипта одновременно:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/flock -xn /var/lock/my_lock_name -c '/usr/bin/php -q /var/www/myhost/my_script.php' >> /var/log/my_script.log 2>&1
```

Данное событие будет запускаться каждую минуту, и если `lock` файла нет, то `php` скрипт запускается. При таком подходе в самом скрипте можно просто проверять необходимость обработки. То есть создать в БД некую очередь.

> хотя таймаут на выполнение запроса стоит около часа

Около часа? Как вы поставили "около часа"?

Comment: Скажите пожалуйста, а почему так мало хостингов предоставляющие услугу `nginx+apache`. Ведь если сайт с статикой и динамикой, то эта связка куда лучше чем просто `apache`.